# How to test all children from a Selector except the first child in Jest

Tags: jestjs

I want to test all children of a Selector except the first Child, if anyone can help I would appreciate it and thank you in advance.

I've tried this but none of those lines worked:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.icons .icon:nth-child(n+2)').hasClass('arrow-right')).toEqual(true);

//////////////////////////////

expect(wrapper.find('.icons .icon:not(:first-child)').hasClass('arrow-right')).toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that enzyme does not fully support pseudo-classes/selectors. Furthermore, the [hasClass](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/hasClass.html) method can only be used in a single node.

Taking that into account, you could do something like:

```
wrapper.find('.icons .icon').forEach(function(icon, index) {
    expect(icon.hasClass('arrow-right')).toEqual(index !== 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you mgarcia, but I already solved it differently. Here is my code:

```jest
wrapper.find('.icons .icon').forEach( (node, index) => { 
    if(index > 0) { expect(node.hasClass('arrow-right')).toEqual(true); }
})
```